# [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'neal'

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update my a row. But it automatically creates an error because the data in a column contains this `Shaquille O'neal` Or are there any problems ?
 Here's my code

```
  <?php
if(isset($_POST['editSubmit'])){
    $buildingID       = $_POST['editBuilding'];
    $buildingName     = $_POST['editBuildingName'];   
    $buildingProject  = $_POST['editBuildingProject'];
    $buildingFloors   = $_POST['editBuildingFloors'];
    $q = "update tblBuilding SET buildingName= '$buildingName' building_projectID='$buildingProject'
          floorNumber = '$buildingFloors'         
          where buildingID = '$buildingID'"; 
    $query = $db-> prepare($q);
    $results = $query->execute();
    echo" <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=project.php'>"; 
}
?>
```

EDITED:
Prepared:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['editSubmit'])){
    $buildingID       = $_POST['editBuilding'];
    $buildingName     = $_POST['editBuildingName'];   
    $buildingProject  = $_POST['editBuildingProject'];
    $buildingFloors   = $_POST['editBuildingFloors'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("update tblBuilding set buildingName=?, building_projectID=?,floorNumber=?  where buildingID = $buildingID");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $buildingName );
$stmt->bindParam(2, $buildingProject);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $buildingFloors );
$stmt->execute();



    echo" <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=project.php'>"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: You need a comma between the columns used for `set`.

Comment: Didn't change a thing :C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is that you're concatenating input data into SQL. This is a no-go: it opens the door wide for SQL injection problems.

Use parametrized queries and your problems should vanish.

Comment: Could you provide an example for parametrized update query?

Comment: Have a look at the PHP docs: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near '('.` Please take a look at my prepared statement. Look in the main post.

Comment: @user4932301 You broke the syntax of the update statement... you really just need to substitute your `$something` with `?` and bind them. That is, `... set column1=?, column2=?, ...` Do it for ALL - including the `buildingID`!

Comment: Sir Lucero, you're a legend! Thank you for the learnings! God bless :D

Comment: Thanks and good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could print out the query. Most likely it's because you wrap the value `$buildingName` using single quote which paired with the one in *Shaquille O'neal* then causes the rest of the query syntax error.